# Why does my text get duplicated to some consoles when I type certain keys?

Tags: console, keyboard

I'm experiencing a strange typing issue that occurs when typing in some consoles. It's not a keyboard issue, because this doesn't happen when I type in a text editor like Atom or a regular application like Word. It doesn't even happen in every console -- repl.it gives me no issues. However, it happens in many coding consoles. I start typing, and when I finish one word and hit the spacebar or a parens or bracket, the thing I just typed gets duplicated out on the same line. Here's a quick video of it happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2S2m.jpg

Comment:   A few places I'd start with: (1) see if any autocorrect settings are enabled by your Operating System; (2) see if the problem persist in other browsers, if no, then disable all browser plugins for the browser you're having issues with (and make sure it's updated), and see if the problem continues to persist (or just use the browser that's not giving you issues)

Comment: Thanks so much @therobinkim for providing input! So I normally use Google Chrome. But on your suggestion, opened up Safari and saw the same issue occur. It doesn't occur on Firefox, however (but other typing issues seemed to appear, like text getting deleted as I typed, without me trying to delete it). I also went in to System Preferences and looked at the keyboard settings and shortcuts. Nothing obviously amiss there. Do you have any other thoughts? If I tend to have browser tab overload, but have restarted my computer a few times, would the restart be enough to ensure that isn't the issue?

Comment: (Btw, @therobinkim, I know you suggested simply using the browser that isn't giving me issues, but I'd prefer to get to the bottom of the issue, as I've read that most web developers use Google Chrome, so I'll need to be able to do the same, and also I know many others who haven't encountered this issue while using Chrome.)

Comment: This problem has been resolved!! Leaving this tip here for posterity: a classmate suggested my issue could be other foreign language keyboards enabled on my system. I had 2 Vietnamese language keyboards and 1 Pinyin keyboard enabled. I tried removing them and now my typing issue is gone. WOOHOO!